# how to add confirmation box in php

Tags: php

Hi This is my php code to delete the excel file from server. Here I want to add a confirmation box before deletion process.

```
<?php
    $files=glob("*.csv");    
    foreach ($files as $list)
    { 
        $file=str_replace(".csv","",$list);?>
            <option value="<?php echo $file;?>"><?php echo $file;?></option>
<?php }?>
     </select>

     <input type="submit" name="download" value="DownLoadExcel">
     <input type="submit" name="delete" value="DeleteExcel">


      <?php

            if (isset($_POST['delete'])=="DeleteExcel")
             {            
                $filename=$_POST['mylist'];
                     if (!empty($filename))
                         {
                             $filename.=".csv";
                             if (file_exists($filename))
                             unlink($filename);
                        }
            }
?>
```

Comment: You should validate the provided file name, otherwise one could probably delete any file.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <input type="submit" name="delete" value="DeleteExcel" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure');">
```

Use in this way

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just add javascript confirmation in onclick event

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="DeleteExcel" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this?');">
```